# Can someone please help me understand the highlighted sentence from the paragraph given down below from the book Dreams From my father?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

“I found myself trying to prolong the conversation, **encouraged less by Miss Omoro’s beauty—she had mentioned a fiancé—than by the fact that she’d recognized my name**.”

Excerpt From: Barack Obama. “Dreams from My Father.” Apple Books.

[image]

Comment: Please give some more details.  What about this sentence is difficult for you?  is it the meaning of the words, the — punctuation — Is it strange that she recognised the name?

Comment: I found sentence difficult to understand.

Comment: Yes, but why? Forget about the extraneous information. Does the following simplified sentence make sense? *I was encouraged less by her beauty than by her recognition of my name.*

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

From comments under the question, the problem results from difficulty in parsing the sentence because of the use of extraneous information that causes confusion.

A simplified sentence that conveys the essential information is understandable:

> I was encouraged less by her beauty than by her recognition of my name.

That is the basic intent of the sentence, and the main construction that's being used.

---

The rest of the sentence is what's causing the confusion:

> **I** <sup>found myself trying to prolong the conversation,</sup> **[was] encouraged less by Miss Omoro’s beauty**<sup>—she had mentioned a fiancé—</sup>**than by the fact that she’d recognized my name.**

While the information in superscript provides additional information, it can be difficult to keep the main part of the sentence in mind at the same time as reading it all together